# How to create iterative organic search code? I'm parsing Log Format website files

Tags: javascript, search, real-time

My keyword-value pair search code is screaming fast but we can make it faster. Here's the code at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Skews_Me/n6k4s6b3/).

When a client calls HashCompactor's .add(keyword,datum) method, it feeds the keyword through a preprocessor which is used to iterate through the keyword. In this case, just assume character is a one-letter string. All keywords beginning with the letter 'a' will found from that node's children, like a tree.

For this question, what's the fastest way to reuse _finder3 and _finder4 to create a _finderN function? You can see from the code that there's a pattern to a _finderN routine, but I'm not sure how best to automate that process.

```
  _findChild: function(node,character) {
    var children = node.children;
    if (children) {
      var child = children[node.currentChildIndex];
      if (child.character === character) {
        return child; 
      } else {
        var length = children.length;
        if (length > 1) {
          switch (length) {
            case 2:
              return this._finder1(node,node.currentChildIndex ? 0 : 1,character);
            case 3:
              return this._finder3(node,character);
            case 4:
              return this._finder4(node,character);
            default:
              return this._fnNodeFinder.call(this,node,character); 
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  },
  _finder1: function(node,index,character) {
    var child = node.children[index];
    if (child.character === character) {
      node.currentChildIndex = index;
      return child;
    }
    return null;
  },
  _finder3: function(node,character) {
    switch (node.currentChildIndex) {
      case 0:
        return this._finder1(node,1,character)
            || this._finder1(node,2,character);
      case 1:
        return this._finder1(node,0,character)
            || this._finder1(node,2,character);
      case 2:
        return this._finder1(node,0,character)
            || this._finder1(node,1,character);
      default:
        // alert("Invalid _finder3 index of " + index);
        return null;
    }
  },
  _finder4: function(node,character) {
    switch (node.currentChildIndex) {
      case 0:
        return this._finder1(node,1,character)
            || this._finder1(node,2,character)
            || this._finder1(node,3,character);
      case 1:
        return this._finder1(node,0,character)
            || this._finder1(node,2,character)
            || this._finder1(node,3,character);
      case 2:
        return this._finder1(node,0,character)
            || this._finder1(node,1,character)
            || this._finder1(node,3,character);
      case 3:
        return this._finder1(node,0,character)
            || this._finder1(node,1,character)
            || this._finder1(node,2,character);
      default:
        // alert("Invalid _finder4 index of " + index);
        return null;
    }
  },
```

Comment: Can you give us an example with input and desired output?

Comment: You've asked your question, but without any context I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is it a some kind of attempt to do your (home)work?

Comment: @KevinCrosby You will surely get help once you update your question with exemplary inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: In the first line of the original comment is a link to a scaled down version of the HashCompactor algorithm in use. And that page also links to time trials.

Comment: The original code sample above accesses the array of child objects to see if the characters match. If not, check the nearby indices. You'll notice that when checking children of length 2, it just flip flops the numbers for the _finder1() call. The characters are individual letters in a keyword, like a tree.

this._fnNodeFinder.call() would be a second part to my question involving searching an array in more than one direction and starting point to take advantage of inherent sorting of the incoming data.

Comment: Keyword-value pairs haven't improved much since the early 1990s when I first discussed HashCompactor, it's been sitting at SourceForge for 11 years, gone through some rewrites, and against static k-v methods my dynamic algorithm comes in a close second to the fastest obj[keyword] (not to be confused with obj.keyword which requires the first keyword character to be a letter. I put it to work sorting website Log Format files by IP address bandwidth use, a feature I couldn't find elsewhere. Now I'm tweaking the guts hoping people know some tricks, notice oversights, and even find it handy.

Comment: I've been wanting a dynamic switch/case routine for ages...

How do we create it? An array of potential values that we eliminate one from and iterate the rest?

Comment: @KevinCrosby Unfortunately I don't have time to read and understand the algorithm you developed. It could even be counterproductive, as reading your code would limit my creativity to come up with something faster (if at all possible). But if you would manage to actually tell us the higher-level problem you want to solve by including some exemplary inputs and expected outputs into this question here on SO, I'd have a go at it.

Comment: Look at _finder3 and _finder4. See how similar they are? It can be turned into an equation. I dread to use things like eval() but I know it can be gracefully done.

Comment: By the way, what keeps you from using `new Map()` with array values? E.g. `add = (map, key, val) => { let data = map.get(key); if (data) data.push(val); else map.set(key, data = [val]); return data; }`

Comment: What's so hard to understand about wanting to develop a dynamic switch statement?

Comment: What keeps me from it? Well, no formal training, for starters. I paint the pretty pictures without the tricks of the trade.

Comment: @le_m How's your version work here?

https://jsfiddle.net/Skews_Me/3ogxez2L/

Answer (score 1):

> what's the fastest way to reuse _finder3 and _finder4 to create a
>   _finderN function?

I suggest a simple for-loop which terminates early when the result has been found:

```
_finderN: function(node, character, n) {
  let currentChildIndex = node.currentChildIndex;
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i === currentChildIndex) continue;
    let child = this._finder1(node, i, character);
    if (child) return child;
  }
  return null;
}
```

If desired, you would still need to handle the `default` case.

> My keyword-value pair search code is screaming fast but we can make it
>   faster.

Usually, the build-in types have superior performance compared to self-made solutions. For performance testing, I recommend using a library such as [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/) which performs warm-up and averages over many test runs. http://jsperf.com/ is a known online performance testing playground built on aforementioned library.

It seems to me that you are implementing some kind of [multimap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap). This can be achieved using the built-in `Map` datatype:

```js
// Simple 'multimap' insertion:
let add = (map, key, value) => {
  let data = map.get(key);
  if (data) data.push(value);
  else map.set(key, data = [value]);
  return data; 
}

let map = new Map();
add(map, 'key', 1);
add(map, 'key', 2);
console.log(map.get('key'));
```

Comment: I have no idea how to use that map function, but if you can munge it into the benchmarking at Fiddle and show it to me, that'd be great. My HashCompactor is typically second against the static array referencing object[keyword]. jsfiddle.net/Skews_Me/3ogxez2L

Comment: Thanks for the heads' up on the let statement. First time I've ever seen it. My JavaScript is all self taught so matching the coding to the algorithm has been a mix and match process. I feel like those elderly artists who create masterpieces by mashing together keystrokes on a typewriter to finally learn there's a backspace key now.

Comment: Don't remember the link, but there was an old, do blocks of loops by 16's. Is there C++ inline functionality (or replacement of) in JavaScript? I want my code to be super fast, I want people to maybe call it Hash() because is is so racing fast, but alas, I'm still running on store bought tires. Tons of tweaks to make to even the smallest details. I built it to be fast, and benchmarking says it's fast. I have it set to sorting IP Addresses by website Log Format bandwidth used, a feature I couldn't find at the time.

Comment: @KevinCrosby `let` is part of the new JavaScript ES6 standard. I recommend Mozilla's [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript) for learning more about those new features. Regarding speed: Unfortunately JS optimization is *hard*. Don't compare it to C/C++. I enjoyed reading [these articles](https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/07/05/v8-a-tale-of-two-compilers) about the amazing technology behind Google's V8 engine - other engines follow similar optimizing strategies. Also: I really recommend jsperf.com - using `performance.now()` etc. gives wrong results (warm-up etc.)

Comment: Seriously, though, my dynamic tree search of keywords is kicking ass against any kind of static wants-to-be-dynamic.

Comment: I would like to know what the impulse response of my filter looks like, though.

Comment: @KevinCrosby hm, I don't follow... did you perhaps mean to add this comment to another answer? If not, what does 'filter' refer to in this context?

Comment: But yeah, the _finderN didn't pass the muster, but switching back to the hard-coded 3 and 4 methods will make a huge positive impact on performance.

Comment: Now I should set up some time trials with the hardcoded tests 3 and 4 to see if 4 is really needed, but I'm trying to think around natural phenomena, so if three is popular in leaves, after four fingers comes a thumb. (Though a 4 digit PIN comes to mind for to account for it, too.) Organic...

Comment: This is what I understand from the internet. With object[keyword] the fastest method short of object.notAnumber_keyword when it comes to finding keyword-value pairs, of all the various methods provided in the benchmarking, o[k] led by leaps and bounds, but mine comes in a 1-2 millisecond behind if I'm not occasionally winning. It's like, hey! I found a new engine, and folks keep downvoting it.

Comment: @KevinCrosby Claiming that anything else than o[k] lookup is faster seems too good to be true and requires extraordinary proof. You need to use jsperf.com or the benchmark.js library to set up valid performance test cases, otherwise nobody will believe this claim. Your current testing method is flawed. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-benchmarking PS: I like what you do, trying to push the boundary. Just use the right measurements and your experimental results will have much more weight.

Comment: I'd really like to see object swapping so that when given a choice between one, two, three, four, and more selections, I find the best fit to need when it comes to search engineering.

Comment: Here's HashCompactor running against o[k]

https://jsfiddle.net/Skews_Me/3ogxez2L/

Comment: I don't know how it explodes: it just does. Edit: but I kinda do cause it reads each character in the stream one by one.

Comment: I've dreamt about such a procedure for decades, but client software can't make it work the grade.

_finderN()

Comment: if (i === currentChildIndex) continue; <-- ha! eyeglasses lost on the head, but the caller had screened out the obvious.